# Grammar for arithmeticthat accounts for integer division

Tags: parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to learn about abstract syntax trees. I'm stuck at developing a grammar that works for integer division.

I've found this one that works for float division:

```
EXP    -> TERM EXP1
EXP1   -> + TERM EXP1 | 
          - TERM EXP1 | 
          epsilon
TERM   -> FACTOR TERM1
TERM1  -> * FACTOR TERM1 | 
          / FACTOR TERM1 | 
          epsilon
FACTOR -> ( EXP ) | - EXP | number
```

But it doesn't work for integer division.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is different about integer division from any other kind of division (or, for that matter, any other operator)?

Comment: During the evaluation of the abstract syntax tree, it evaluates x/y as (1/y)*x. This expression holds for float division, but not for integer division.

Comment: That's not a problem with your grammar; it's a problem with the way you construct (or evaluate) the AST. Although I can't help thinking that it would all be easier if you used a normal expression grammar instead of one which has been "adapted" to top-down parsing. In a standard bottom-up grammar, the factor production would look something like `Term -> Factor | Term * Factor | Term / Factor;` and each production would include both arguments to the operator.

Comment: I do understand that. The problem is I don't know how would I go about parsing from the bottom-up.

Comment: The simple solution would be to use a parser generator like `bison`. If you want to learn about ASTs, as opposed to how to build LALR(1) parsers, then it is certainly not cheating to use an existing parser generator :) Otherwise, figure out how to transform your parse tree into an AST, since the point of an AST is that it is *not* precisely the parse tree. (That's the reason it's called Abstract Syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Could point me towards a book or an website where I could learn more about AST's and parsing in general?

Comment: The most important thing about ASTs is that they be usable for solving whatever problem you need to solve (evaluation, compilation, semantic analysis, etc.), so there is no "standard". But usually they are just a condensed version of the parse tree, as the wikipedia article indicates. Pretty much any compiler text would provide more detail -- the Dragon book continues to be popular afaik -- or you could look at the LLVM tutorial (http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html) for a more practical approach.

Comment: @rici Thanks. I'll delete the questions in a few hours, as I don't think it has a correct answer. If you want to answer it though, please do.